# How to align 2 mat-slide-toggle fields on different rows

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a form which has 2 slider toggles on separate rows.  The requirement is to have the label on the left side of the slide so I set the property labelPosition="before" on each control.  However due to the difference in number of characters of the labels the sliders are not aligned to each other.  Is there a way this can be achieved.

I have tried to  look if there are any styles that can be overridden in the CSS or any suitable attributes on the element.

Here is the HTML I am using:

```
<div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <mat-slide-toggle labelPosition="before" color="primary">Automated Balance Check Enabled</mat-slide-toggle>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <mat-slide-toggle labelPosition="before" color="primary">Balance Threshold Enabled</mat-slide-toggle>
        </div>
      </div>
```

I would like to get both slider's aligned but they are not as shown in this screenshot [image].

There needs to be more space on the second mat-slide-toggle between the label text and the actual slider. I can work around this buy adding multiple spaces after the text 'Balance Threshold Enabled'.

Answer (score 1):

You can try defining `.mat-slide-toggle-content` class in your CSS given a fixed size.
This class is applied to the span with the label text, so it could work, but i have not tested.

Comment: Thank you that worked. I can specify a fixed width.  I can add it to my external css and it works fine.  However I would not want this fixed width on other pages if I want to use the slider toggle in the future.  I tried adding the style as internal CSS to the top of my page as follows but it does not work.  Is there a way around this?  `<style>
  .mat-slide-toggle-content{
    width:280px;
  }
</style>`

Comment: You should define a css file only for the actual component, and add this styling there. See [the angular tutorial](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles)

Answer (score 0):

try below code for your solution

````
    <div fxLayout="row"><mat-label fxFlex="40%">Automated Balance Check Enabled</mat-label>
<mat-slide-toggle fxFlex="60%" labelPosition="before" color="primary"></mat-slide-toggle></div>
  <div fxLayout="row">
<mat-label fxFlex="40%">Balance Threshold Enabled</mat-label>
<mat-slide-toggle fxFlex="60%" labelPosition="before" color="primary"></mat-slide-toggle></div>```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can specify mat width, height with css vars like this

```css
:host {
    --mdc-switch-track-width: max(calc(100%), 60px);
    --mdc-switch-track-height: 20px;
}
```